# Creating nested folders in firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I've got one FirebaseDatabase reference and two FirebaseStorage references in my class. 
First StorageReference is ProductImages and second reference will be the push key that I'm going to get from the DatabaseReference.
But the problem is that when I'm uploading the images in the storage no second reference is created. All the images are being stored in the ProductImages reference.
Is there any fault in my code? 
Is this a limitation of Firebase? 
Or is there any other way to create nested folders in Firebase Storage programmatically?

I've attached the code :

```
private DatabaseReference productRef;
private StorageReference productImagesRef, imageRef;

productRef =   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference().child("Products");
productImagesRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProductImages");

final String key = productRef.push().getKey();
imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProductImages").child(key);

imageRef.putFile(mainImageUri)
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to upload!!! Try Again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                   mainImageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            });

    imageRef.putFile(sideImageOneUri)
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to upload!!! Try Again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener( getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                    sideImageOneUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I wonder if the character in the push ID are causing problems. Can you try with only hardcoded names? E.g. `imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProductImages").child("Subfolder");`

Comment: @Amrit, Let us know which type of nested folders you want to make.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried your method but the result is the same. The same thing is happening with your code and my code. Only one image is being stored in the storage and instead of creating a new folder named "SubFolder", the image is being named as "SubFolder.jpeg"

Comment: @niveshshastri I want to have a folder named "ProductImages". This folder should be able to hold many sub folders such as product1, product2,..... These sub folders should be able to store image files. But the problem with my code is that no sub folder is being created and all the images are being stored in the "ProductImages" folder.

Comment: @Amrit, you can't create nested folders with your code, you have to update your code for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
productImagesRef.child(key).putFile(mainImageUri).....
productRef.child(key).putFile(sideImageOneUri)....
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I didn't create same storage reference. Please read the question carefully. First reference is : FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProductImages"); ........... and second reference is : FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProductImages").child(key);.......... They are different.

Comment: sorry sir, kindly review my new suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, I think I've got an acceptable answer. I created different references for different images that I'm storing. Code is following :

```
private DatabaseReference productRef;
private StorageReference productImagesRef, imageRef, mainImgRef, sideImgRef;

productRef =   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference().child("Products");
productImagesRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProductImages");

final String key = productRef.push().getKey();
imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProductImages").child(key);

mainImgRef = imageRef.child(mainImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
sideImgRef = imageRef.child(sideImageOneUri.getLastPathSegment());


mainImgRef.putFile(mainImageUri)
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to upload!!! Try Again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        })
        .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
               mainImageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        });

sideImgRef.putFile(sideImageOneUri)
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to upload!!! Try Again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        })
        .addOnSuccessListener( getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                sideImageOneUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        });
```